# columns aren't functioning properly

Tags: css

i am trying to set up three columns but they are laid out directly beside each other, no gutters.

seemingly, i can also put an endless amount of columns across the row and the "4" specification will not stop at 3 columns.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
   <p>Test<br>Test description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p>Test<br>Test description</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you can provide more information about the problem. Presumably you are using some version of bootstrap?

Comment: @colinsmyth Bootstrap uses padding and not margins for gutters so you will not see a gap between the box edges if you are using a background color for the boxes. You should see the text padded though. The easiest solution if you'd like boxes with margins is just to add a div inside the col-xs-4 container.

Answer (score 0):

In head, try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

That is cdn to bootstrap version 3

Grid in bootstrap is 12. if you need for 4 row. you can add `.row` again in another `div` you can see documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)